# Rival Executioner draws Robespierre...does this end the day?

Tags: guillotine

The Rival Executioner card requires that, upon his execution, you take the noble from the top of the deck and "collect" it. My friend drew Robespierre, who, when collected, ends the day.

We didn't like the way it affected the game (my friend was in second place, and it was day three), so we let it go. But I'm still curious...do you reap the side effects of the card drawn after beheading the Rival Executioner?

Rival Executioner reads:

> Collect the top noble of the noble deck after you collect this noble

Robespierre reads:

> The day ends after you collect this noble. Discard any nobles remaining in line.

Comment: If you you don't like the high variability of having days suddenly end, you can always just remove Robespierre and the Scarlet Pimpernel. There's still plenty of luck left in the game without them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you end the day if you collect Robespierre via the Rival Executioner.

The game only has one verb for the process of operating the guillotine: "collect." When a noble is collected, you do all of the side-effects of that noble. Guillotine is a mix of tactics and luck, so drawing Robespierre due to the Rival Executioner is well in line with the way the game typically plays out.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have to follow the rules and end the day.

This is a very simple, but extremely fun game due to it's luck and unpredictability, if you take that away, you are taking the soul of the game away.

There's always another round to play and many more chances to play again.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, as others have said. The trigger word is "collect" which applies regardless of where you collect the noble from.

It's also worth mentioning that there are other cards that also have effects regardless of where you collect them from, such as the **Fast Noble**, who allows you to collect an extra noble from the line.